# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Custom UI Pattern

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, ui-patterns

I'm trying out the mobile pattern, and have been trying to crate my own custom pattern that is now supposedly supported in Worklight 6.1.

When I tried creating jquery UI pattern, several issues:
1. The rich page editor for the pattern.html does not display the jquery component correctly on the design page (e.g button is displayed as link).
2. When I added a new page (into a jquery hybrid app) based on the custom UI pattern, it does not create a new page. It only adds the content code into the index.html, and I had to create the page myself.
Is this the correct behaviour?

I'm also having difficulty in creating Dojo UI pattern… as there is no Dojo component available on the palette when I open up the dojo > pattern.html file. 
Do I have to add the libraries and code manually (i.e. no Drag-and-Drop)?

Appreciate any pointers on this.

PS: I'm using Eclipse Juno R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) For jQuery based patterns you need to append a jQuery core file to the project besides the jQuery mobile ones, for example, append this one: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js to your project, next to jquery mobile JS file. This is just because "UI Pattern" projects don't have this file available, but they need it to handle a proper preview.

2) For Dojo patterns, there is still no official support (for example Drag and drop), so even you can modify pattern.html to get some "insertable" code, you may still need some additional tuning to get a valid pattern.

Comment: Thanks Orlando! One thing that's still buggy is that whenever I want to add my query custom pattern, the Studio does not create the page/view for me automatically. It simply inserted the pattern content code in my HTML file. Maybe it's a bug. 
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I believe you need to have a page/view as the main node of the pattern itself. That will do the trick.